# Intellij Idea project files encoding is reset after clicking on Maven IDE "Reload project"

Tags: java, windows, maven, intellij-idea, encoding

I am working on IntelliJ IDEA v2022.3.2 on a Java 11 project with Maven 3 on Windows 10. In the project settings I have set the file encoding to UTF-8 for all src/main/java source folders.
However, every time I click on "Reload project" in Maven IDE, the file encoding for all src/main/java folders is then set to ISO-8859-1.

I would like the file encoding to stay in UTF-8. In my pom.xml parent, I have set the following properties :

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

Where does this ISO-8859-1 encoding setting is coming from ?

[UPDATE]

Seems like my local machine default encoding is ISO-8859-1 :

```
PS U:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default                                                                                                                                        

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Europe de l'Ouest (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

Isn't there a way to tell Intellij/Maven to use another encoding than system default ?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a sample project and the steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `.mvn` folder in root of your project
- add `jvm.config` file in that folder i.e (`.mvn/jvm.config`)
- Add `-Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dproject.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8` to the file
- Checkin this file in your repo
- MVN will try to find this config file when you run and will use it

Comment: I already tried that : I have set global encoding and project encoding to UTF-8. So I do not know where the ISO-8859-1 is coming after clicking on Maven IDE "Reload Project".

Comment: try setting default configs: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: Where do you configure encoding in default settings ?